# Why are squares instead of whitespaces appearing in my HTML?

Tags: html

Everything's fine in FF3 but I'm having a weird issue with Chrome and to a lesser extent IE7+, on a Win7 PC, where whitespace characters in my HTML content are being represented by squares. I'm using HTML5 and I believe I have the correct encoding (utf-8).  Does anyone know why this would be happening or what I'm doing wrong?

http://berkshiretheatres.com/dev/

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Try http://doctype.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be coming from your CSS font setting in body. If you inspect the element in Chrome and disable the style the issue goes away.

```
body {
   font-family: LiberationSansRegular;
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks...that's what I get for using boilerplate stylesheets.

Comment: An update, it appears that the @font-face kit I got from Font Squirrel was corrupt.  I dl'd it again and all is good with LiberationSans.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a binary viewer to ensure you have the correct whitespace character (0x20 in UTF-8 I think).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in the text itself. According to my binary text editor, it's a good old `U+0020` space.

If you use the "Inspect element" feature you can see that the squares are gone if you disable this rule:

```
body {
   font-family: LiberationSansRegular;
}
```

... found at http://berkshiretheatres.com/dev/wp-content/themes/html5/style.css?v=1294931627

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, it's due to the used font type (font-face), you need to include other font types for the font your are using in you css depending on the targeted browsers.

For me, I prefer using `woff`, Support for `woff` can be checked at http://caniuse.com/woff.